Writing recursive code to find unmatched parenthesis in a string?
I'm currently working on some code in SystemVerilog to find matching parenthesis in a string. The code takes in an array called str that holds n characters, each 4 bytes long. The string will have open parenthesis, closed parenthesis, and other arbitrary characters such as spaces or periods. I already have a working code to do this non-recursively:
module pmatch_comb_base
  #( int n = 5, wn = $clog2(n) )
   ( output logic [wn-1:0] left_out_n_unmat_close, right_out_n_unmat_open,
     input uwire [3:0] str[0:n-1] );

   always_comb begin

      left_out_n_unmat_close = 0;
      right_out_n_unmat_open = 0;

      // Scan string from left to right. (Leftmost character is at i=0.)
      for ( int i=0; i<n; i++ )

        if ( str[i] == Char_Close ) begin

           // We've found a closing parenthesis, ")".

           if ( right_out_n_unmat_open > 0 )
             right_out_n_unmat_open--;  // It matches an opening parenthesis.
           else
             left_out_n_unmat_close++;  // It's unmatched, update the count.

        end else if ( str[i] == Char_Open ) begin

           // We've found an opening parenthesis, "(".

           // Increment the count of unmatched open parentheses ..
           right_out_n_unmat_open++;
           // .. which might be decremented in a later iteration.

        end
   end

endmodule

How would I go about doing this recursively? I'm finding it difficult to work out exactly how to mimic the logic above with a recursive approach. For some examples, if the string looks like "))((" the values of the outputs should be open = 2 and close = 2, "(())", "()()", and "(()())" should give open = 0 and close = 0, and "(. ())(" should give open = 1 and close = 0.
I first tried to make a base case of when n is equal to 1. Then I made another case to split the number of characters n into two using new variables and parameters, a lo and hi, then recursively call the module with these two halves and at the end calculate the total matches and leftovers, but doing so kept giving me errors, and this is where I got confused about the logic of the approach.


recursively call the module

A Verilog module represents a hardware component, like a shift register or an ALU.  You don't really "call" a module as much as you place an instance of one, like on a PCB.
A better approach is to call a function recursively.  Refer to the
IEEE Std 1800-2023 section 13.4.2 Static and automatic functions.  There is a code example for a factorial function which demonstrates the principle.

verilog describes hardware. The latter is called so, because no dynamic structures are allowed there. Recursion is dynamic in nature, since there is no defined depth to it. Same is about lists and other dynamic structures.
The task of a verilog designer is to map dynamic structures into a limited static presentation, e.g. lists can be mapped to arrays with max size. Recursion can be flattened and the stack be mapped to such an array as well. The latter, however will require that the length of the string has a reasonable maximum to manage the stack.
You can try the above, but recursion could be less efficient in performance and use of hardware than the non-recursion algorithm.

Just like with a for loop you want to iterate over the input string one character at a time and end when the whole string has been inspected.
The recursive function, therefore, needs parameters passed in that are the string, the current index and the two counters.  The base case is when the index equals or exceeds the string length.
Pseudo code:
recursive_function(input_string, cur_index, open_count, close_count)

  // base case
  if (cur_index >= input_string.length) return; 

  // Check current character at using your existing logic to increment open_count or close_count.
  if (input_string[cur_index] == ...

  // call the recursive function with the next index and updated counts
  recursive_function(input_string, cur_index + 1, open_count, close_count);
  
end

Update this function so to use proper syntax for functions, for calculating string length and return value.  Not sure if you want to return True/false or and integer.
Then you start by calling the function with the first index.
recursive_function(some_string, 0, 0, 0);

